# How to merge cells in the table dynamiclly

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to merge cells in a table, I know the most obvious way - using the **rowspan** attribute.

```
 <table>
   <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">data</th>
      <td>
        first_data_element: 1 second_data_element: "abc"
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        first_data_element: 2 second_data_element: "xyz"
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

However, in fact my table in created dynamically - cells content is get from a database - so I have to use ***ngFor** directive

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">data</th>
      <td *ngFor="let el of data.dataElement">
        species: {{el.firstDataElement}} weight: {{el.secondDataElement}}
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However this doesn't work,
Note that teh value of rowspan is permanently entered.
What I need is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the attribute binding in Angular, in order to set the value dynamically use it like below:

```
<th [attr.rowspan]="data.dataElement.length">data</th>
```

Please find the doucmentation here : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding

Please find the working stackbitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rln5dj

Comment: It still doesn't work properly, data is show next to each other, other data is put in another column

Comment: can you create a basic stackblitz or can you create a basic picture that states how you need it.

Comment: I updated my post, If I add this attribute nothing changes, th element is in one column and data elements are next to each other - to the right of th element

Comment: Great job, thanks, I put *ngFor lopp in wrong place

Comment: Happy to help :)